# How do I do argmax in KDB?

Tags: kdb

Let's say I have a list:

```
(1 2 3)
```

I'd like to find the index of the maximum value (`2`).

What's the right way to do this in KDB?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few different ways, but here is one using the find operator `?`

```
 1 2 3?max 1 2 3
```

Answer (score 2):

`where` will return indexes based on a condition:

```
l:1 2 3;
where l = max l
,2
```

https://code.kx.com/q/ref/where/

Answer (score 0):

[Find](https://code.kx.com/q/ref/find/) `?` will get you the index of the *first* occurrence of the maximum; [`where`](https://code.kx.com/q/ref/where/) and Equal the indexes of *all* occurrences.

You can use either of these with the [Zen monks idiom](https://community.kx.com/t5/Community-Blogs/Meet-the-Zen-monks/ba-p/11604):

```
q)show L:10?7
4 5 6 6 1 0 5 2 4 5
q).[?] 1 max\L
2
q)where .[=] 1 max\L
2 3
```

Why might you do that? Since these expressions are sequences of unaries, you can compose them, eliminating the (tiny) overhead of a lambda – in case you were doing this where small differences in speed mattered.

```
ffm:.[?] max\[1;] @        / find first maximum
fam:where .[=] max\[1;] @  / find all maxima
```